# In Java, can you use negative one with substring?

Tags: java, string, substring

Can negative one be used as the end index for string.substring in Java?

Example:

```
String str = "test";
str.substring(0, str.indexOf("q"));
```

Edit: Nowhere in the javadocs does it say directly that **endindex** cannot be negative. There are implementations of substring in other languages and libraries that allow a negative endindex but **disallow** a negative beginindex, so it seems relevant that this be explicitly stated. It is not in any way implied either. (Edit: ok it is implied loosely, but I and apparently others who have asked me this question in person still find it pretty unclear. This was meant to be a simple Q+A that I provided not me actually trying to find an answer to this trivial question)

Comment: Here's a static helper method which allows negatives from my custom `StringUtil` class: `public static String substring(String str, int begin, int end) {
    if (str == null) [ return null; }
    if (begin < 0) {
        begin = str.length() + begin;
    }
    if (end < 0) {
        end = str.length() + end;
    }
    return str.substring(begin, end);
}`. I also have a `StringUtil.substring(String begin)` which calls the other one with the length of the String for end.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

*No*. Negative indices are *not* allowed.

From [String#substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#subSequence(int,%20int)):

> Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the *beginIndex is negative*, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or *beginIndex is larger than endIndex*.

While the documentation does not directly state that endIndex cannot be negative<sup>1</sup>, this can be derived. Rewriting the relevant requirements yields these facts:

1. "beginIndex cannot be negative" -> `beginIndex >= 0`
2. "beginIndex must be smaller than or equal to endIndex" -> `endIndex >= beginIndex`

Thus it is a requirement that `endIndex >= beginIndex >= 0` which means that endIndex *cannot* be negative.

---

Anyway, `str.substring(0, -x)` can be trivially rewritten as `str.substring(0, str.length() - x)`, assuming we have the same idea of what the negative end index should mean. The original bound requirements still apply of course.

---

<sup>1</sup> Curiously, [`String#subSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#subSequence(int,%20int)) *does* explicitly forbid a negative endIndex. Given such, it feels that the documentation could be cleaned up such that both methods share the same simplified precondition text. (As a bonus: there is also an important typo in the "Java 7" subSequence documentation.)

Answer (score 6):

**No**, using negative numbers for the endindex of substring as well as a number greater than the string length will result in an StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

(You wouldn't believe how hard it was to find a straight answer to this on the net)